# Is there a way to use Generics to deduce/narrow the value type in this example?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm looking for a way to deduce/narrow the type the property name in the following snippet. What I tried so far doesn't seem to work. The goal is to get **some** level of type safety, similar to what someone would get within an `if` statement by writing a [discriminated union](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/discriminated-unions#discriminated-union).

```
type UserProperty = Pick<User, 'firstName'|'lastName'|'age'>;

// This type doesn't properly deduce the type of 'propertyValue' based off 'propertyName'
type OnChangedFunction<T extends UserProperty = UserProperty> = (args: { propertyName: keyof T, propertyValue: T[keyof T]}) => void;

class User {

  private readonly _onChangedCallback: OnChangedFunction;
  constructor(onChangedCallback: OnChangedFunction) {
    this._onChangedCallback = onChangedCallback;
  }

  private _firstName: string = "";
  public get firstName(): string { return this._firstName; }
  public set firstName(v: string) {
    if (v !== this._firstName) {
      this._firstName = v;
      this._onChangedCallback({ propertyName: "firstName", propertyValue: v });
      
    }
  }

  private _lastName: string = "";
  public get lastName(): string { return this._lastName; }
  public set lastName(v: string) {
    if (v !== this._lastName) {
      this._lastName = v;
      this._onChangedCallback({ propertyName: "lastName", propertyValue: v });
    }
  }

  private _age: number = 0;
  public get age(): number { return this._age; }
  public set age(v: number) {
    if (this._age !== v) {
      this._age = v;
      this._onChangedCallback({ propertyName: "age", propertyValue: v });
    }
  }
}

const f: OnChangedFunction = (args) => {
  if (args.propertyName === "firstName" || args.propertyName === "lastName") {
    console.log(`I'd like to know that the type for '${args.propertyName}' is 'string' when writing my code! (${args.propertyValue})`);
  }
  else {
    console.log(`I want to know that the type for '${args.propertyName}' is 'number' when writing my code! (${args.propertyValue})`);
  }
}

const u = new User(f);
u.age = 56;
u.firstName = "John";
u.lastName = "Doe";
```

Link to [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAqgZygJwArIPbWeGBeGVASwGMBrAHkRQBoYByAMyOQRADkBDAWynoB96AG05suvAfU4BzPgD4A3MGAB6FTAAqACyIIY4aDAAmGKAgB29EDAiZsQsMahGAriVggtHyLAyMGtlgo4ABqnEIufDAARqLOMH7%209IHY4OJ8oD4wAPLmAMJanOayRgBiLuYkIEQY5hQaMFAAHiBQ5kZ61Gh2wY4EXehBOGBy%20DAAFJzI0ggAXDAA3jY9w%20nzZFBgfpp0Kb1hEVDzGgDaG1v%20GgC6AL4AlPijAG4YREZKwCQiCJ1IyIvKGDLIhPTitGDIKCcEzmBwwAD6tQKRRKeXCQli5HmuWRxWc5Uq1VqSiBJFqbGQbhAGGQ4yRhTxRjRQgxnCxOXyDJKBKqNXMDwWwCBQM8ugAdIjOSjnMzWeQxvTpUz0ZiyCSYDdAcDQeD4cxWBweEcYBSiMUxgAiC3qiAuaJCUgwWTWfViI3jO7zU3mpaQkAuZDmfQ6BAS12G3gKDVCmx2h0kE1QF0sN28cZPL0gZBm6QCmNAoj%20dMwACEeAIotDepTEageeFwsrYZr6TGT3VDabktxqJVbLI4yWe1WRvmFvD6QtuxWoXCkXmTw1dw7wvz0aBmpjthBYNg8O%20tcz2fNBCtNrjjudMAP6Q9R5ziwhSYDQa7N6NUc1QNt9sdSGs75phmJpZjm9bCoWEyLmWFYhhKgF1gCDYinB%206iLWbYrih4rdlyMp9uQg7LEMaSjjAFoIVOxGpGABzzjAi73CuX7Rlu2Y6nuMjGuYLjcNEKBjAADOev4JleXF3jAPF8QJvrPoGwY4Vxn5bheCb-jAEnAdJ-HIOBBZFl2XGluWDH6Y2qHGQQ7ZrthVaKoysqqkRw6kbwY5cVRrm0XOxqMcua4sZqm5kuYbAwIw2JSoyPJEkGBCTNMCAPHgoyCgZExTDMYrea25anhORoWjA-D8JpSU5TOYB5aZFHoZO5mhQgGBCFAYpCBg0jjAABgAkvQRjXkQGz6BgMBkOYGAAO7BmCwbeIYjA0gwAAkCxZaGuVGjc9AwLoDDetIu1TV4QZTdm1TmtwjhkkYUAlhMa0bZVJE%20Yc9zdQFG4xlAQhIEhwpNS1bUdV1fUwFNRTWNS42TTNnhzZ4C2wEt-z0E9FVbbwO17Xo9A6Sgx2nRDF0PtdMC3fdj3rZjVV0VAH1fdGIXktYLhjOYUAzV04yMAFLhilZMAAKwAGxKALhW8JaABSGBaOY1rAALCGWgAIqY1pAA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need here is distributed union. Currently your arg has type like this:

```
type Old = { propertyName: 'firstName' | 'lastName' | 'age', propertyValue: string | number };
```

But to use it in way you want it needs to be something like this:

```
type New = 
    | { propertyName: 'firstName', propertyValue: string }
    | { propertyName: 'lastName', propertyValue: string }
    | { propertyName: 'age', propertyValue: number };
```

So later when you check value of `propertyName`, TS can narrow this union to related members.

To do this you need to distribute it by key/`propertyName`. This can be done with `X extends any` or `X extends infer Y` construction. In your case it will be something like this:

```
// Just 'container' for argument type
type Arg<K, V> = {propertyName: K, propertyValue: V};
// Actual trick is 'K extends any' which makes union distributes (e.g. Test<1> | Test<2> | Test<3> vs Test<1 | 2 | 3>)
type DistributedArg<E, K extends keyof E> = K extends any ? Arg<K, E[K]> : never;

type OnChangedFunction<T extends UserProperty = UserProperty> = (args: DistributedArg<T, keyof T>) => void;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.4.2#code/FAFwngDgpgBAqgZygJwArIPbWeGBeGVASwGMBrAHkRQBoYByAMyOQRADkBDAWynoB96AG05suvAfU4BzPgD4A3MGAB6FTABSAVzYMSGAHYhORAynoxGGZDE7JpW3kZjhooSLACC9igGk6AGpy+DAA3hCY2ODiUABcMP4wEVgo4AGcQlpxMAEAvkpqMJ4kIFoZLsikZDBECAy+MFAAHiBQBgAmdZwGYBYA7gAWpAMw3JxkUHVaBkSGMO21IJUARlqtdQAUUAB00tswACqTIBQAjMH8h8cUAEwXV2wUAMzBAG51R4+nMJc3PzAvACU7mgMAAIosVmsoO1vNIKABROgNZqtDp1CZgDCMGAI4IEFEtNqdWw9GAAfiKPkSCIA2r4ALrBeJmV4oJQg2AAeQMAGEBt1ZO0AGLTEqzAwUA6NIno+BINCRVJgELURUpHBgfEwDZ2aQIeIQthQ1qwnwHOiY7GHOSA-BvDBEdockgiBB1NVhZQwJKVV6cVowZBQTjtQxCFUAfUM-MFMN5GSEy045HiPNjBiFooM4sMSh9+gMxq0JWsGxjAsz8cTydTMHTlazYpAErtoWAPp9ICGCG20b5jerQiTKeqBArcfaCeHtbI+ZguW9vqI-sDkeYrA4PGyxtM0hCACID-OIFplkJSDBZCBLCwxNuNoD4rvM2Eg1BSsgDC4e32N-feAUBcOySM8LxIGAkBvf8t14DZXmfJY9zbECfSIHF4JgABCPACG7Wo-zvWCoBQztO3w3t1yImIQleecyIovsJyrKca1HDZQl9DVom3eIDxgmIDzoZIojAdJMmyV4F0BejO1Q4CfUXECIhXANYEjN1iMQypXwII8TzAy9rxgTSYkfbS9zfYNP2-RiNNEYigMXH1T3PS8oJMhyzIQyCkMzUjO3QnUpJwvDf3sgCSK9Miu3C0zt1o2TYoI-sMyFacR3IDiuNEmI+Pi3ghJy5VxKyeIpNyGT5Oc4DlL9NSYEjGRsgMRxlhQEIAAYDLciDjOa8yYFa7h2psTjrK0L8fxS5qnOUwyII8gafOG0aArQjC7Oa7DcJgV51vI8LtoIOj5OSyjmPStiss4kTlTymAD2aoq7s1UrJOk2SasXJTC10Rg0wHSds1zb8CF1ewEDtPBgnbDadT1XtXp43h8F2-jqO3A8fkuRHtmRsAaNwvSCqgA8DrxgmYnkv6MCEHYhAwaQNgAAwASXodoTKICYXAwGAyAMDA+h-AMf1gVxYCsGx6AAElCSmlU1GJcgsWoGBfaR+gGNoYD6SoW1fbgVX0dooCwnV5cV7ixIyLJKpZqrFJAqAhCQaLO1p+ntkZ5n2b17obxAfnBeF0Wg51lwPEsawGCtyH8aVlGoFVmo6noVbzD1nXv31ohDf3Y2YFN83LYVhOCfeh2neA37DF0LQQjMEW1Q2Rgqq0bZjpgABWAA2JRO4EhK9I0DABgMY9gE70nDzBDAyYUIA)

Comment: Interesting that `K extends any ? Arg<K, E[K]> : never` resolves to something different than just `Arg<K, E[K]>` - is it more accurate to classify this as a clever hack, or the intended usage of typescript's ternary?

Comment: It seem as a hack to me too, but it's useful and quite actively used now too